# Logo and title in header Ionic (left-center)

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to be able to have a logo and a title in the header of my app. Currently, my app is organised this way :

index.html that wraps the other views :

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable headerBar">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

And I have my tabs with ion-view. Before modifications, I had the parameter view-title for each tab and align-tile center in the index, and I had a title in the center of the header, but I want to have a logo on the left, and the title on the center. So what I did was this :

```
<ion-nav-title>
    <img src='img/helpro.png' class="title-image"/> {{ 'devices' | translate }}
</ion-nav-title>
```

But this way, I have the logo with the text in the left too. How can I do to have the logo on the left, and the title on the center ? I tried to have the tag nav-title and the parameter view-title, but nav-title override the view-title. If I do align-title center it takes both.

This is my current page :

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Have you try with the attribute "side" in  <img src='img/helpro.png' class="title-image"/>? You can specify in which side to align that, then you only need to align the text to the center or middle.

Comment: "If I do align-title center it takes both." If you do that on what element? Entire ion-nav-title? How about placing 2 spans inside of it and floating 1 left? Would that work